# Manually create modules and their dependencies with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

We do a modular application where the UI is divided in components/modules like billing area, staff management, real time charts, shipment etc... The customer pays for this component/module and only the modules he paid for shall be loaded on client side. I name these paid modules "main modules" on client side because every main module is route/button to sub content where user with different claims can do different things.

What I would like to do now is before angular is initialized I would like to manually create the modules basing on the array of licensed module names. Those modules who are not licensed are not created.

Here I have an understanding problem and can not find any similar case in google.

1.) How can I tell angularjs to load a specific module with all its attached controllers/services and their depending modules?

2.) What happens with the common javascript includes which will cause an immediate creation of the angularjs modules?

Comment: Sort this problem server-side,no really,dont let angular decide what to load what not to load.You may be using a templating engine on the server,use it to tell javascript what to load/what not to load,generate the markup for angular templates, you can even generate javascript from the server ... The otherway around is to recreate all your role/account/acl management in the client,which wouldnt be that DRY.

Comment: Why close? Please state a reason! This is a legit question!

Comment: @mpm I sort this problem server side that my endpoints are modularized. So the user can only browse to certain routes when the module is loaded with the endpoint else he gets a 404... HOW can I server side manipulate angular and the modules?

Comment: The server can restrict which template or module to load , the server can be ask if a given route is allowed or not . the server can do many things,mainly bootstrap the angularjs application. Isnt your server serving content at first place ? then the server can generate the javascript needed to run the application.

Comment: I remember hearing something about this in a video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=62RvRQuMVyg#t=486).  That guy's use case is very similar to yours: conditional feature loading

Comment: @mpm Thank you for the hint. Its very good to decide on server side which javascript files aka modules are copied over to the index.html file sent to the server. That way I have a single source of truth!

Comment: @JonathanWilson The guy in the youtube video is doing it EXACTLY the way I suggest it :P Include only the features/scripts which are needed by the user inside the index.html.

Comment: De rien;) what would be great is that if no one answers your question after a period of time,just post an answer yourself describing how you did manage to solve your issue,and mark it as the correct answer.Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

User @mpm put me on the right track. Its the best if all the files belonging to a angular module are copied over to the index.html before the body tag before the Index.html is initially sent to the client side. That way the client does not know about how the modules are loaded. It just gets the modules... Only the server knows and is doing still more stuff about the modules to be licenced like loading only the module depending endpoints/ApiController`s.

To second this answer as a recommend approach, you can watch this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=62RvRQuMVyg#t=486

from the angular conference where they recommend the same approach :-)